# CryptoJS.AES.encrypt giving different result in android (kotlin)

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, cryptojs

Android client needs to use the same encryption which is used in our other Javascript application. i.e.

```
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(getSecretKey()); 
const piv = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 16);
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(piv);
const miv = piv + userCredentials;
const msg = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(miv);
   
val msg = "64 character long string"
val key = "32 character long string"
val iv = "32 character long string"
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, {
      keySize: 16,
      iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
```

I tried using the following in Kotlin

```
val key = toHexString(getSecretKey())
val iv = toHexString(getCurrentUTCTime())
val msg = toHexString(getMessage())
 
//1. Create a cipher object
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")

//2. Initialize cipher
val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(),0,16,"AES")
val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv.toByteArray(),0,16)
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec)

//3. Encryption and decryption
val encrypt = cipher.doFinal(msg.toByteArray())
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypt)

private fun toHexString(bytes: ByteArray): String {
        val formatter = Formatter()
        for (b in bytes) {
            formatter.format("%02x", b)
        }
        return formatter.toString()
    }
```

Both are returning a different value. Can someone please tell that if both algorithms which are same, their configs are same, their keys are same why are they returning a different value?

Comment: It could be a good idea if you present a sample dataset (key, iv, message and ciphertext). Another note: why do you cut the key and iv from a 32 character long string to a 16 bytes long byte array ?

Comment: i have access to android code only, not the javascript code. So just need to replicate whatever is there. Also I solved this, it was due to I was converting the key, iv, message and ciphertext to hex. Because in javascript code it was doing something like this: const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(piv) so i was converting it to hexString in kotlin. After removing the hexString it was working fine.

Comment: Good to read that you solved your problem. The hex encoding was my first thought (32 to 16 bytes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
val key = toHexString(getSecretKey())
val iv = toHexString(getCurrentUTCTime())
val msg = toHexString(getMessage())
```

I had to remove the function calling.

```
val key = getSecretKey()
val iv = getCurrentUTCTime()
val msg = getMessage()
```

then both results were same on javascript app and on android client.